# Why is my onTouchEvent being triggered without touching the screen?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

The onTouchEvent method always says that the event is 0 (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) once I touch the screen for the first time. I don't know how to get it to report when I stop touching the screen.

The stage variable tells it what tap number it is on in the three part process (start, stop, and release)(made for a catapult like game)

`public static int stage = 0;`

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                stage++;
                System.out.println(stage);
                handleTouches();
                System.out.println(onTouchEvent(event));
                return onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

```
    public void handleTouches() {
        if (stage == 1) {
            runPowerBar = true;

        } else if (stage == 2) {
            runPowerBar = false;
            tree.startAnimation();
            bg.startFlight(power);
        }
    }
```

```
    public void update() {
        tree.update();
        setCoins(context, 0);
        //setCoins(context, coins);

        if (runPowerBar) {
            powerBar.powerBarSlider();
        }
        System.out.println(runPowerBar);
    }
```

The update method is called by the method below in the MainThread

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                    this.gameView.update();
                    this.gameView.draw(canvas);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {} finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the onTouchEvent to tell me that the action is down when i touch and up when I'm not but it just stays on 0 for down.

Update 7/22:

Alright so after some testing I found out that the update method still runs, but 
my draw method freezes once I tap the first time and it resumes after the second tap.  Also it now says when I release a tap.

Comment: consider `OnTouchListener`.

Comment: you are calling onTouchEvent(event) with your printing of the log, I don't think this is intended

Comment: Thanks, I removed all that and it now waits for me to tap before it goes, the only thing is that it pauses everything else until I tap again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a recursive function there, you call `onTouchEvent` with the `ACTION_DOWN` event recursively.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Start of touch events 
                stage++;
                System.out.println(stage);
                handleTouches();
                System.out.println(onTouchEvent(event));
                //return onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // End of touch events
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Moved touch events
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Oh no, your primary issue was you returning `onTouchEvent`. I just added the other cases to show an example since you said that you didn't know how to get a report when the screen touching is stopped.

Comment: Alright thanks, it now waits for touch, except it pauses everything else until I tap again. Any help with this?

Comment: What do you mean by, it pauses everything? Do you mean like, the UI thread freezes (and you get an ANR), or do you have a specific animation or something that stops?

Comment: In the update method I have System.out.println(runpowerbar); and this constantly outputs false until I tap and then It stops outputting this message until I tap again.  Based on this I would think that something froze up, since my update method stopped running.  I also have a method that moves the power bar selector back and forth after the first tap, but instead it just stays still.  I know this works though because after the first tap it appears at a different spot than the last time.

Comment: Where are you calling this `update` method and what does it do. Add the code to the question.

Comment: `public void update() {
        tree.update();
        setCoins(context, coins);

        if (runPowerBar) {
            powerBar.powerBarSlider();
        }
        System.out.println(runPowerBar);
    }`  This is just inside my GameView class.  Sorry about the formatting

Comment: And when is this called? Also, add the code to the **question**, not in the comments.

Comment: Please hurry, since this is for my 4H fair, and it has to be done by Tuesday.

Comment: I can't seem to find any mistakes in the code you've posted. Maybe you could try printing the `Exception` that you seem to be ignoring in the `run`block.

Comment: Maybe `this.gameView.draw(canvas);` doesn't get executed since an exception gets thrown from the function used in the line preceding it.

Comment: Also, determine if your UI thread is freezing (and you're dropping frame. Try taking a [systrace](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#systrace) and also [enable profile gpu rendering](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering#profile rendering).

Comment: Alright, I added the exception in the run, and this.gameView.draw(canvas); is not being run after I tap, but the line before it does get run.

Comment: What exception is being thrown??

Comment: Aha! I figured It out. I feel so stupid now, it was the runPowerBar() method.  I had a while loop in it so when the update method started it just waited in that until I tapped again to stop the while loop.  Thanks for helping out and being so patient!

Comment: Chill, happens. See you around mate. :)